# How fast / efficient is Bluebird's timeout?

Tags: promise, timeout, bluebird

The following example times out in most cases (outputs `timed out`):

```
Promise = require('bluebird');

new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
})
    .timeout(1001)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('finished');
    })
    .catch(error => {
        if (error instanceof Promise.TimeoutError) {
            console.log('timed out');
        } else {
            console.log('other error');
        }
    });
```

Does this mean that the Bluebird's promise overhead takes longer than 1ms?
I see it often time out even if I use `.timeout(1002)`.

The main reason for asking - I'm trying to figure what the safe threshold is, which gets more important with smaller timeouts.

---

Using Bluebird 3.5.0, under Node.js 8.1.2

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking.  Bluebird's `.timeout()` just uses `setTimeout()`.  You can see the source here: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/src/timers.js#L70

Comment: TBH, I would consider this a bug. Timeouts with different millisecond integers should be strictly ordered, and promises should resolve before the event loop turns for the next macro task (timeout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have traced your bug in Bluebird's code. Consider this:

```
const p = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
const q = p.timeout(1001); // Bluebird spawns setTimeout(fn, 1001) deep inside
```

That looks rather innocent, yeah? Though, not in this case. Internally, Bluebird implemented it something like (not actually valid JS; timeout clearing logic is omitted):

```
Promise.prototype.timeout = function(ms) {
    const original = this; 
    let result = original.then(); // Looks like noop
    setTimeout(() => {
         if result.isPending() { 
            make result rejected with TimeoutError; // Pseudocode
         }
    }, ms);
    return result;
}
```

Bug was presence of line `ret.isPending()`. It resulted in brief time when `original.isPending() === false` and `ret.isPending() === true` because "resolved" status didn't propagate yet from `original` to children. Your code hit that extremely short period and BOOM, you had race condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's going on here is that there's a race between the time the rest of the promise chain takes and the timer from the `.timeout()`.  Since they are both so close in timing, sometimes one wins and sometimes the other wins - they are racy.  When I run this code that logs the sequence of events, I get different ordering on different runs.  The exact output order is unpredictable (e.g. racy).

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

let buffer = [];
function log(x) {
    buffer.push(x);
}

new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        log("hit my timeout");
        resolve();
    }, 1000);
}).timeout(1001).then(() => {
    log('finished');
}).catch(error => {
    if (error instanceof Promise.TimeoutError) {
        log('timed out');
    } else {
        log('other error');
    }
});


setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(buffer.join("\n"));
}, 2000);
```

Sometimes this outputs:

```
hit my timeout
finished
```

And, sometimes it outputs:

```
hit my timeout
timed out
```

As has been mentioned in the comments, if `.then()` was always executed via microtask (which should precede any macrotasks), then one would think that the `.then()` would precede the `setTimeout()` from the `.timeout()`, but things are apparently not that simple.

Since the details of promise `.then()` scheduling is not mandated by specification (only that the stack is clear of application code) a code design should not assume a specific scheduling algorithm.  Thus, a timeout this close to the execution of the async operation it is following can be racy and thus unpredictable.

---

If you could explain exactly what problem you're trying to solve, we could probably offer more concrete advice about what to do.  No timers in Javascript are precise to the ms because JS is single threaded and all timer events have to go through the event queue and they only call their callbacks when their event gets serviced (not exactly when the timer fired).  That said, timer events will always be served in order so a `setTimeout(..., 1000)` will always come before `setTimeout(..., 1001)`, even though there may not be exactly 1ms delta between the executing of the two callbacks.

Comment: This is not a good example, because `console.log` is a heavy operation, and it changes things, so you cannot use it before calling `resolve`.

Comment: But in my example I only use `console.log` after the timeout, so it cannot affect the outcome, imo.

Comment: @vitaly-t - It's an unpredictable race between whether the `setTimeout()` event from the `.timeout(1001)` gets in front of the `.then()` or `.catch()` in the event queue.   Remember, since all `.then()` and `.catch()` are async, other things can interleave with them.  Because you don't know how long the promise chain takes to run, you can't guarantee it all finishes before the `.timeout(1001)` timer runs.  When I run it with `.timeout(1002)`, I can get either result because the exact timing of one vs. the other is unpredictable.

Comment: This is weird though - shouldn't Bluebird (especially in Node) use microtask semantics for resolving promises, so that the promise is fulfilled before the second timeout callback hits?

Comment: @Bergi - I see your point.  How exactly the scheduler works in Bluebird on some specific platform is beyond my pay grade (meaning I can't quite figure it out by looking at the source).  It appears to favor `setImmediate()`, but there's a lot of other options in [the code](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/51aabb4e5412c82ded0d92692cc899e02e0f334d/src/schedule.js).  Aren't you connected to the project or some of the people on it?  Perhaps someone on the project could interject here.

Comment: @Bergi - But, since the exact scheduler is not dictated by specification, the code in the OP's question just appears racy to me, an ill-advised design and testing shows that it is indeed unpredictable - giving different sequencing on different runs.

Comment: I don't know myself. Let's wait for @BenjaminGruenbaum to show up, or maybe I'll open an issue at Github.